# How to add bias to a classifier in scikit-neuralnetwork?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, neural-network

The docs do not mention any method for initializing the bias neurons. I am getting considerably low accuracy after fitting. I guess this is because of the absence of the bias neurons in the network.

Comment: Ever found a solution?

Answer (score 0):

Per the docs, [`MultiLayerPerceptron`](http://scikit-neuralnetwork.readthedocs.org/en/latest/module_mlp.html#multilayerperceptron) accepts a `weights` argument as a list of `(weights, biases)` tuples for each layer. To check whether the biases are changing during training, you could check `get_parameters()` before and after fitting.